# How does the query method #group work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, querying

I'm learning rails and have been trying to read through documentation, but I just don't get how [#group](http://devdocs.io/rails/activerecord/querymethods#method-i-group)
 works.

The documentation says that it: "Returns an array with distinct records based on the group attribute".

How do you then retrieve the records that belong to a certain group?

Say I want to group `Articles` by the month in which they were created? How would I do that?

Comment: You need to read more about what the SQL `group by` clause actually does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `group` method is generally used with the `select` method to do aggregating queries. For instance, if you wanted to **count** your articles by month, you could do this:

```
by_month = Article.group(:month).select("month", "COUNT(*) as count")
```

In this case, `COUNT` is the SQL aggregate function that counts rows, and we're putting the count result into an output column called "count".

Note: This assumes you have a column called "month". Of course you can do SQL here, so you might have, e.g. `MONTH(created_at)` instead, or whatever makes sense in your case.

You could then do this to output the month and its associated article count:

```
by_month.each do |row|
   puts "Month #{row.month}: #{row.count}"
end
```

This probably seems mysterious because your model has no column "count", but that's the way `select` works: It defines new output columns for the query on the fly, and ActiveRecord happily maps those for you in the resulting instance objects.

This kind of query is dramatically more efficient than loading all the records and counting them yourself because you're letting the database do the heavy data work, and that's what it's good at.

It is perfectly legal to use `group` without `select` but the result is not usually what you want. If you group your articles by month, you'll get one object in the result for each month. The columns available in each object vary by database back end, but in MySQL they will have the values from the "first" row encountered for each group. If you aren't sorting, "first" is essentially undefined.

If by "group Articles by the month in which they were created" you mean you want this kind of grouping on a web page result, then you'll have to do it yourself, e.g.:

```
<% last_month = nil %>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <% if last_month != article.month %>
      <h2><%= article.month %></h2>
      <% last_month = article.month %>
   <% end %>

   # [output the article]

<% end %>
```

If you do something like this, you'll need to be sure `@articles` is ordered by month.

Comment: So if I understand correctly... the result of `group` is an array. As far as what is in the array, there is an object that holds the articles for month1, an object that holds the articles for month2 etc. And then... for each object in the resulting array, `select` takes it, counts how many articles it holds, and returns that value.

*Is that right?*

Comment: That's close to right. But really, the *database* is doing the counting before Rails ever sees the data. So group resolves to an array that already has one entry per group with the counts set. This way you only send the final result across the wire for reconstituting into objects. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you referring to [lazy evaluation](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-queries)? So the only thing I'm still shaky on is what the objects in the array look like? It's an object that holds the articles for a given month. How does it do that? Like what attributes and methods does it have?

Comment: It doesn't hold the articles for a month. It holds the results of the query. It is confusing, but this is a SQL feature, not an ActiveRecord feature. If you use `group` without a `select` then you just get the "first" article from each month. If you use `select` then you can add to this things like count, min, max, average, etc... But you never get *all* the articles in the month. It is one object per group in the array. It is an `Article` instance object, and its attributes depend on the `select`. You can play with it on the rails console to get a feel for it. And read up on SQL `group by`.

Comment: Ahh ok, that last comment makes a lot more sense and clears things up. Thanks! It seems that to know Rails, I really have to know SQL, so I'll study up on that. So if I wanted to show links to all the articles in a given month, `group` wouldn't be the right choice (because you can't get all the articles in a given month)?

Comment: Right. See the last code snippet in my answer for how to do what you want. But add this to the start (or, more likely, the controller): `@articles = Article.order(:created_at)`. If you want to show all the articles in a list (grouped or otherwise) then you don't want `group` in your query.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again, your explanations have been a big help and I appreciate it.